How to pass a reference to Supabase instead of an object in a Cloudflare Worker
I created supabase client and pass reference to supabase into the fetch function; this is the code:
```
 addEventListener(“fetch”, (event) => {
   const supabase = createClient(SUPABASE_URL, SUPABASE_KEY)
   event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request, {supabase:supabase}));
 });

 async function handleRequest(request, obj) {
 ...
 else if (request.url.includes("script.js")) {
 return new Response(js(request, obj.supabase), {
   headers: { "content-type": "text/javascript" },
 });
 ...

Inside my script I implement my algorithm and the Supabase operation  needed for my algorithm, something like this
```
const js = (request, supabase) => {
  return ` 
  send = document.getElementById('send') 
  send.supabase=${supabase} 
  .... 
  }});`
}
export default js;
```

Without supabase all works fine, but I watch my script now in browser and see
const send = document.getElementById('send')
send.supabase=[object Object]

How to receive reference in this place instead object?

I resolved this issue by injecting the supabase client to worker:
const js = (request, supabase) =>  {
    return `
import { createClient } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@supabase/supabase-js/+esm'
const supabase = createClient('${supabase.URL}', '${supabase.KEY}')
...

I have injected the Supabase Key and Url in the boilerplate level, and then created supabase client in the worker level. Of course, this is a less secure solution since anybody can see your Key and Url. Therefore Row-Level Security for Supabase must be added and configured.
